# What scope does a C++ friend live in?

Tags: c++, scope, friend

I have some (real world) code that has a structure basically like so:

```
class C
   {
   public:
      C(int x = 0) : m_x(x) {}
      friend int foo(const C& c, int y) { return c.m_x + y; }
   private:
      int m_x;
   };

class Z
   {
   public:
      int foo(int y) {
        // The problematic call:
        return foo(c, y);
      }
   private:
      C c;
   };
```

I understand that the call to `foo` inside `Z::foo` needs to be disambiguated. The thing I don't understand is, what scope is appropriate? I expected the declaration of the `C`-friend `foo` to be in the global namespace, but calling as `::foo` does not work, both GCC and Clang report this as an error.

However, if I change the declaration of `C`+friend to:

```
class C
   {
   public:
      C(int x) : m_x(x) {}
      friend int foo(const C& c, int y);
   private:
      int m_x;
   };

   int foo(const C& c, int y) { return c.m_x + y; }
```

Everything works, I can (in `Z::foo`) refer to `::foo`.

So here is my questions: in the first example, what scope is the `C`-friend `foo` in, if it is not in the global namespace? Is there no way to refer to the global `foo` from within `Z::foo`? And, what is the difference between my first and second examples?

Comment: What do you mean "needs to be disambiguated"? From what?

Comment: @StoryTeller It's called in the member function `Z::foo`, which has the same name and overload resolution prefers it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I may be too used to overloaded operators, but I could swear the friend `foo` is part of the overload set.

Comment: @StoryTeller If I understand the rules correctly, that is only the case in `C` itself, not anywhere else (prior to ADL of course). http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#unqual-9.sentence-1

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I don't think that's the relevant paragraph. We are talking about a name used in a member, not in a friend. I think it's http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#argdep-3 . Pretty much says finding a member flat out stops ADL. I wonder... What would be the harm?